# Functions differentiable at the irrationals and not differentiable elsewhere

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I provide [here](http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/a-differentiable-function-except-at-point-with-bounded-derivative/) an example of a real function that is differentiable at all reals except at $0$ and which has a bounded derivative.

**Edit:** and which do not have left and right derivatives at $0$.

Do you other examples of that kind of functions?

And [here](http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/a-continuous-function-not-differentiable-at-the-rationals-differentiable-elsewhere/) I provide an example of a function differentiable on $\mathbb{R \setminus Q}$ and not differentiable on $\mathbb{Q}$. Do you also have other examples? Not using function series?

Comment: This is an interesting website and it looks like you put a lot of effort to make it both useful and pretty. I hope it will continue to grorw.

Comment: I think that $f(x)=|x|$ is such an example for your first function ?

Comment: Thanks Kelenner for you remark. I updated the post in order to add the condition that I missed.

Comment: Thanks Erel for your encouragement! By the way, I have a lot of fun to develop this website... Just lacking time sometimes.